# What happens to the UICollectionView maintained cell queue on receiving memory warning?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

When UICollectionViewCell objects are not visible they are added to the queue for reuse. If memory warning occurs what happens to the cells in the reusable queue. Is the queue cleared and cells destroyed or are they left as they are?

Comment: Why would you care? If it is destroyed you should be creating a new one anyway, so it shouldn't really bother you

Comment: @Lefteris lets say I have different cells with heavy content occupying large amount of memory. It would be added advantage if I know what happens in that case when a memory warning appears. Its good to know if I can rely on the system or else need to clear that memory.

Comment: Put the heavy content in an autorelease pool then

Comment: Hey, here what is the queue means?.. Dispatch queue or any other?

Comment: @PhaniRaghu its the UICollectionView instance's reusable queue

Answer (score 0):

If you some how keep a strong reference to your cells then they will not be removed and you will have tones of those cells. also you have to remember if your cell didn't dequeued properly and you have a strong reference to the cell then your tableViewController will not be reinitialise as well.

Comment: I dont keep strong references to the cells in my case. I just want to know in general what happens to the queue in the event of memory warning as its implementation is hidden.

Comment: No body want to keep reference to the cells but it happens some times the result your scrolling speed starts getting jerky till your application gets out of memory and system will kill your application

Answer (score 0):

On receiving memory warning, cells objects which are not visible are cleared out from memory at the same time dequeue manager handles this process internally.

To know more, how memory management works? Run your code in simulator.

Print the cell object which provides address obtained by it. Later select **Hardware** option in menu to generate memory warning.

```
"row = 7 ->  cell = <UICollectionViewCell: 0x7ff8b89096e0; frame = (2 1935; 371 265); clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x61800003da20>>"
```

This will help you understand more on address management also.